# Setup automatic PC turn on

Tags: python, windows, shell, taskscheduler

Is there a way to setup automatic boot up on PC and login to desired windows account without using task scheduler interface or BIOS settings?

I want to do it by some kind of script for example batch or python, not using WakeUpOnLAN solution.

Tried searching for some Task Scheduler module for Python or similar solutions with no success.

Using Windows 10.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: Windows, added to post.

Comment: Your question isn't really very clear. Are you asking how to make the PC boot up at a particular time, or how to make it do something automatically after it boots?

Comment: just boot up the pc

Answer (score 0):

You can use `puppet` for the purpose.

Refer:

https://puppet.com/presentations/managing-windows-puppet

https://github.com/counsyl/puppet-windows/blob/master/manifests/autologon.pp